# Positioning absolute div within parent div

Tags: html, css

just need some help here for my css layout..here my attempt so far are shown below..

[image]

As my desire goal is want to positioning the float button just bottom of the background image...as shown belown..

[image]

and here are the html and my css so far

```css
.bg-image {
  position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-image button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 4px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div data-role="content" id="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
      <div class="bg-image" style="background-color:#CFD8DC;">
        <img id="imgupload" src="//dummyimage.com/1000x200" />
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-fab ui-btn-raised clr-warning"><i class="zmdi zmdi-camera zmd-2x"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the `bottom` of `.bg-image button` to "negative half the height of the button", so it might be something like:

```
.bg-image button {          
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -28px;
    right: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..i've change the css but it shown half of the button and thats something i dont want to happen.... @SeanKendle

Comment: Try adding `overflow: visible` to the parent container, `.bg-image`.  Or, if it's at the bottom of the page, you'll need to add a margin on the bottom of `.bg-image`, like `margin-bottom: 28px` (equal to the negative bottom of the button)

Comment: It works like charm now..thanks @Ivan Rodriguez Torres and SeanKendle